# Регулярное выражение , все что между знаками *

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

Есть комментарии в коде:

```
/* /templates/images/icon.png */
```

как с помощью RegExp выбрать все что между звездочками, + сами звездочик со слешами:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

пути будут разные только по длине, могу цифры попадаться.

`([/*-*/])\w+` - так не получается

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Лучший вариант этого выражения — развернутый `(?s)\/\*.*?\*\/`, который выглядит как

```
/\/\*[^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*\//g
```

См. [демо регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/56B8Qi/1).

Подробности:

- `\/\*` - начало комментария `/*`
- `[^*]*\*+` - 0+ знаков, отличных от `*`, за которыми следует 1+ згаков `*`
- `(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*` - 0+ последовательностей:

  - `[^\/*][^*]*\*+` - символ, отличный от `/` и `*`, за которым следует 0+ знаков, отличных от звёздочки, за которыми следует 1+ звёздочек
- `\/` - закрывающий знак `/`.

Минус только в том, что если нужно получить только то, что между `/*` и `*/`, нужно будет убрать последнюю букву с помощью, например, `substr`.

```js
var regex = /\/\*([^*]*\*+(?:[^\/*][^*]*\*+)*)\//g;
var str = "/* /templates/images/icon.png */\n/* /templates/images/icon.png \n* Тут тоже бывает текст\n*/";
while (m = regex.exec(str)) {
   console.log("Полное совпадение: " + m[0]);
   console.log("Без /* и */: "+m[1].substring(0,m[1].length-1).trim());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Не ясно, по какому принципу вы строили вашу регулярку, так должно работать.

```js
console.log("asdsa/* /templates/images/icon.png */cvsdv".match(/\/\*.*\*\//)[0])
```

Comment: строил с помощью стороннего сервиса

Comment: Неверно: `1 /* 2 */ 3 /* 4 */ 5`

Comment: @Qwertiy ну скорее ответы - это быстрый намёк автору, что делать на его примере, а не детальное продуманое решение)

Answer (score 1):

Например, так       :

```
 \/\*.*\*\/
```

Comment: а квантификаторы `^` и `$` точно нужны?

Comment: @АндрейNOP да, не нужны конечно.

Comment: Неверно: `1 /* 2 */ 3 /* 4 */ 5`

Answer (score 1):

Основная проблема этой задачи - правильное экранирование:

```
/\/\*.*\*\//g
```

```js
let str = 'before/* /templates/images/icon.png */after';
console.log(str.match(/\/\*.*\*\//g))
```

Задачу экранирования можно решить отдельно:

```js
function e(str) {
  return str.replace(/[\-\[\]\/\{\}\(\)\*\+\?\.\\\^\$\|]/g, "\\$&");
}

let str = `before/* \n /templates/images/icon.png */after/***/`;
let regex = new RegExp(e('/*')+'[\\w\\W]*?'+e('*/'), 'g')
console.log(str.match(regex), regex)
```

Comment: Неверно: `1 /* 2 */ 3 /* 4 */ 5`

Comment: Зависит только от постановки задачи. нежадный режим включить не проблема.

Answer (score 1):

если в файле множество таких строк тогда можно сделать таким образом

```
 var str = "/* /templates/images/icon.png */ /* /templates/lol/icon.png */";
        var reg = /\/\*(.*?)\*\//g;
        var l = str.match(reg).length;
       for(var i = 0;i<l;i++){
        var result = reg.exec(str);
        var one = result[0];//вся запись
        var two = result[1];//все что между звездочками
        console.log(one+":"+two);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Если могут быть многострочными:

```
/\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\//
```

Если только однострочные:

```
/\/\*.*?\*\//
```

Comment: А подскажите плиз, каким образом `?` в регулярке влияет на результат так, как модификатор `U` в PHP? Честно говоря синтаксис регулярок JS менее знаком, и реже используется, хоть и в основном схож, поэтому и забываешь, что это разные вещи..

Comment: @ГончаровАлександр, в php это работает абсолютно так же: https://regex101.com/r/QDmAEY/1

Comment: @vp_arth интересно, вопрос `?` означает "может быть, а может не быть" - то есть если при анализе регулярки встретился символ после вопроса, который "может быть" , считается что совпадение найдено, анализ идёт дальше, такая логика?

Comment: Вопросительный знак после квантификатора (`+`, `*`) имеет другой смысл. А именно, смена режима жадности этого квантификатора.